# Can't handle specific status code error in Retrofit with Rxjava while using a base extension fuction for handilng Exception

Tags: generics, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to call an API function of my server. I implement that using Retrofit and Rxjava and make a base exception handler method 'toSingle()'. API call is successful. but the problem is when the server sends a response with status code 406, the message did not show. Instead, it shows null value

`BaseResponse.kt`

```
open class BaseResponse(
    @SerializedName("status") val status: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("message") val message: String? = null
)
```

`LoginResponse.kt`

```
data class TutorLoginResponse (
    @SerializedName("data") val data: TutorLoginCredential
) : BaseResponse()
```

`Extension.kt`

```
fun <T: BaseResponse> Single<Response<T>>.toSingle(): Single<T> {
    return map {
        if(it.isSuccessful) {
            it.body()
        } else {
            if (it.code() == 406) {
                throw Exception(it.body()?.message)  // Can't get this message from BaseResponse Class. Show null 
            } else {
                throw Exception("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LoginService.kt`

```
@POST("signin/tutor")
fun tutorLogin(
    @Body loginBody: LoginBody
): Single<Response<TutorLoginResponse>>
```

`LoginViewModel.kt`

```
fun tutorLogin(email: String, password: String) {
        compositeDisposable += authenticationService.tutorLogin(email, password)
            .toSingle()
            .doOnSubscribe { }
            .doAfterTerminate { }
            .performOnBackgroundOutputOnMain()
            .subscribe({
                
            }, {
                handleException(it)
            })
}

fun handleException(throwable: Throwable) {
    when(throwable) {
        is IOException -> toastMessage.value = Event("No Internet Connection")
        else -> toastMessage.value = Event(throwable.message.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem. The code is given bellow

`Extension.kt`

```
fun <T> Single<Response<T>>.toSingle(): Single<T> {
    return map {
        if(it.isSuccessful) {
            it.body()
        } else {
            if (it.code() == 406) {
                val error = Gson().fromJson(it.errorBody()?.charStream(), BaseResponse::class.java)
                throw Exception(error.message)
            } else {
                throw Exception("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
}
```